# How to get opening hours on nodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-maps, web-scraping

I am trying to get restaurant listings for a data analyst project. This is trying to search for restaurants in Seattle. I'm thinking why it couldn't get opening hours is due to selectors. The current output of this includes name, address, phone number and plus codes.

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import xlsx from "xlsx";

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set the navigation timeout value
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);

  await page.goto("https://www.google.com/maps/@48.1403077,17.1036957,70m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu");

  // Set screen size
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });

  // Type into search box
  await page.type("#searchboxinput", "restaurant+seattle");

  // Wait and click on first result
  const searchResultSelector = ".mL3xi";
  await page.waitForSelector(searchResultSelector);
  await page.click(searchResultSelector);

  await page.waitForSelector(".hfpxzc");
  const places = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    const element = await page.evaluateHandle(
      (index) => document.querySelectorAll(".hfpxzc")[index],
      i
    );

    if (element) {
      try {
        await element.click();
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        await page.waitForSelector(".CsEnBe");
        await page.waitForTimeout(1500);

        const placeName = await page.evaluate(
          () => document.querySelectorAll(".DUwDvf")[0].innerText
        );

        const existingPlace = places.find((place) => place.name === placeName);

        if (!existingPlace) {
          const items = await page.evaluate(
            () => document.querySelectorAll(".CsEnBe").length
          );

          const info = {};

          info["Name"] = placeName;

          for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
            const innerText = await page.evaluate(
              (index) => document.querySelectorAll(".CsEnBe")[index].innerText,
              i
            );

            const tooltip = await page.evaluate(
              (index) =>
                document.querySelectorAll(".CsEnBe")[index].dataset.tooltip,
              i
            );
            // Wait for 1 second before proceeding iteration
            await page.waitForTimeout(1000);
            if (tooltip == "Copy address") {
              info["Address"] = innerText;
            } else if (tooltip == "Open website") {
              info["Website"] = `https://www.${innerText}`;
            } else if (tooltip == "Copy phone number") {
              info["Phone Number"] = innerText;
            } else if (
              tooltip == "Open menu link" ||
              tooltip == "Place an order" ||
              tooltip == "Open reservation link" ||
              tooltip == undefined
            ) {
            } else {
              info[tooltip] = innerText;
            }
          }

          places.push(info);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      await page.evaluate(() => {
        const scrollElement = document.querySelectorAll(".ecceSd")[1];
        scrollElement.scrollBy(0, 300);
      });
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(places);
  const wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
  const ws = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(places);
  xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Data");
  xlsx.writeFile(wb, "Places.xlsx");

  await browser.close();
})();
type here
```

I am getting quite confused with the selectors, tried manually and AI, but they don't seem to work, any idea on how I can get opening hours from this.`your text`

Comment: Would the Places API work for your use case? It might be simpler to implement and the Text Search API returns object that includes opening hours - places.currentOpeningHours.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of data you need is relatively small, you can directly use the API provided by Google.

Google Maps search returns up to 120 results. To scrape more results, such as all restaurants in New York City, large area must be split into small areas before searching. You can use free google map scraper to achieve this goal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the site you're using?

Comment: FYI: LetsScrapeData.com